# Convert String to java.time.localDate

Tags: java

1.way

```
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(reservationDTO.getReservationDate());
```

2.way

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(reservationDTO.getReservationDate(), 
    formatter);
```

3.way

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(reservationDTO.getReservationDate());
```

I try convert String to java.time.localDate but for this 3 ways i have error

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-7-11' could not be parsed at index 5
```

Comment: The month part should be on 2 digits, i.e `'2018-07-11'` .

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd"` does not match the passed date of `"2018-07-11"`

Comment: 1. and 3. are the same.

Comment: Thanks I add 0 in month add work fine

Answer (score 2):

Pls notice this line

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Specially format `yyyy-MM-dd`

You configure to pass a Date of Format with **4 Char of year, 2 Char of Month and 2 Char of Date**. But you are passing only 1 Digit in month.

So what you need to pass is `2018-07-11`

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change `reservationDTO.getReservationDate()` you need to use only one `M`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-dd");
LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(reservationDTO.getReservationDate(), 
formatter);
```

As you can see in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) `M/L` matches with 7, 07, Jul, July, J

Otherwise, if you can change `reservationDTO.getReservationDate()` just transform `2018-7-11` into `2018-07-11`

Answer (score 0):

The date string you are trying to parse is not proper. Date should be 'yyyy-MM-dd' e.g '2018-07-24'. You are trying to parse the string 2018-7-24

Answer (score 0):

i think this example will resolve your problem.

```
 String startDateString1 = "06/27/2007";
    String startDateString2 = "2007-06-27";
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"); 
    Date startDate1;
    Date startDate2;
    try {
        startDate1 = df1.parse(startDateString1);
        startDate2 = df2.parse(startDateString2);
        LocalDate localDate1 = DateTimeUtils.toLocalDate(startDate1);
        LocalDate localDate2 = DateTimeUtils.toLocalDate(startDate2);
        System.out.println("localDate1:" + localDate1);
        System.out.println("localDate2:" + localDate2);
        System.out.println("Result: " + localDate1.isBefore(localDate2));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```